# Are there ablaut changes in romance languages?

Tags: romance-languages

The ablaut system was in [Proto-Indo-European](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut). It also is present in some English, German and Greek. Are there ablaut changes in romance languages such as Italian, French and Spanish?

Comment: Do you mean productive ablaut, or historical traces of ablaut?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All Romance languages have some historical traces of ablaut. For example from Spanish:

**hacer**`"to do/make"`: infinitive with **/a/**
**hice** `"I did/made"`:  preterite with **/i/**
**hecho** `"done/made"`:  past participle with **/e/**

French
**faire**`"to do/make"`: infinitive with **/ɛ/**
**fis** `"(I) did/made"`:  preterite (passe simple) with **/i/**
**fait** `"done/made"`:  past participle with **/ɛ/**

Portuguese
**fazer**`"to do/make"`: infinitive with **/a/**
**fiz** `"I did/made"`:  preterite with **/i/**
**feito** `"done/made"`:  past participle with **/ej/**

Romanian
**a face**`"to do/make"`: infinitive with **/a/**
**făcui** `"I did/made"`:  preterite with **/ɨ/**
**făcut** `"done/made"`:  past participle with **/ɨ/**

Italian
**fare**`"to do/make"`: infinitive with **/a/**
**feci** `"I did/made"`:  preterite (passato remoto) with **/e/**
**fatto** `"done/made"`:  past participle with **/a/**

However this now acts like root suppletion and is not productive with new words. Occitan and Catalan have [productive vowel-altering processes sometimes called ablaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan_phonology#General_ablaut), but they are not derived from PIE ablaut and are not grammaticalized.

Comment: Do you consider the *-ir* stem-changers to have an ablaut change in the 3p preterite?  There are zillions of these: *morir > murió, dormir > durmió, pedir > pidió, sentir > sintió, advertir > advirtió, reír > rió*, perhaps *adquerir > adquiso*. Also, when  listing things in modern Romance, it might help to add the corresponding Latin, so one can see that the vowel changed there, too, like *fácere, fáciō, fēcī* in this case.   ES *saber > supe* is another good one that tracks the Latin perfect *sapuī* well in other Romance tongues.

Comment: @tchrist. This is not about ablaut; it is about the fact that Latin /o/ and /e/ develop differently in penultimate and antepenultimate syllables.